# Facebook access_token retrieving

Tags: java, facebook, spring, model-view-controller

Good day.

I`m trying to integrate with facebook. So i need users to login with facebook to my site and then i need to get their information such as friend list etc.

I do the follows:

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
    public void facebookLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,String code) throws Exception
    {
        // ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        // Facebook did not accept this user yet...
        if(code==null||code.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            String facebook_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?";
            //                facebook_url+="client_id="+ Settings.getStringSetting("app_id");
            facebook_url+="client_id="+ "12849129...344";
            facebook_url+="&scope=publish_actions,friends_hometown,friends_status,friends_birthday";
            facebook_url+="&redirect_uri="+domain+ "/facebook/login";
            facebook_url+="&state="+ "DDFFRREEiiFF";
            response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
            response.setHeader("Location", facebook_url);
        }
        // Facebook accepted our user
        else
        {
            // Getting token to use facebook API
            String getTokenURL  = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                    +"client_id="+ "128491....344"
                    +"&redirect_uri="+domain+ "/facebook/login"
                    +"&code="+code
                    +"&scope=publish_actions,friends_hometown,friends_status,friends_birthday"
                    +"&client_secret="+"fc160e2ab...235254240c";
            //friends_hometown
            String result = HTTPClient.sendHTTPRequestWithMethod(getTokenURL, "GET");
            String access_token = extractParams(result).get("access_token");
            // Get user...
            String get_user_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="+access_token;
            String user_str = HTTPClient.sendHTTPSRequestWithMethod(get_user_url,"GET");
            JSONProcessor proc = new JSONProcessor(user_str);
            System.out.println(proc.getStructure());
            HashMap<String,Object> user = proc.getStructure();
            String facebook_id = proc.getStructure().get("id").toString();
            DBRecord rec = dbProc.getUserByFacebookId(facebook_id);
            User u = new User();
            u.setValue("facebook_access_token",access_token);
            u.setValue("facebook_id",facebook_id);
            u.setValue("first_name",user.get("first_name"));
            u.setValue("last_name",user.get("last_name"));
            u.setValue("facebook_name",user.get("name"));
            u.setValue("birthday",user.get("birthday"));
            u.setValue("facebook_code",code);
            u.setValue("facebook_link",user.get("link"));
            u.setValue("gender",user.get("gender"));
            u.setValue("facebook_photo_url","https://graph.facebook.com/"+user.get("id")+"/picture?type=small");
            if(rec==null)
            {

                Long user_id = u.createInDB(dbProc);
                u.setValue("id",user_id);
            }
            else
            {
                u.setValue("id",rec.getID());
                u.saveToDB(dbProc);
            }
            setCookie(response,"facebook_code",code,86400000);
//            return new ModelAndView("/user/main_choose");
            response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
            response.setHeader("Location", "/user/main_choose");
        }
    }
```

So i expect users first come to /login without code parameter and i redirect them to `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth`
Then they are going to login to facebook and it should redirect them back to /login , but add "code" parameter and then i could call `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token` with that "code" parameter to retrieve access_token for current user. With that token i`ll be able to do all i need.

So when i try to login from my account (account of developer) - it goes fine. But when i try to do it from other account (of my friend for example) - i see facebook login form, but after redirection i still have no "code" parameter.

Why? 
Here is my app configuration:
Site URL: `http://109.173.122.47/`
Canvas URL: `http://109.173.122.47/`
Sabdbox mode: ON

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but hope you know about frameworks that can handle/simplify this for you - for example, I'd recommend you check out the Spring Social project http://www.springsource.org/spring-social

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the `sandbox mode` is `enabled`?

If `sandbox mode` is `enable` you are the only person who authorize to use that app,